# Tab-ing with Carousel

Tags: html, tabindex, wcag, wcag2.0

I'm having this one problem while working on improving accessibility. What I'm trying to achieve is when I press tab I want the focus to go from 1 - 2 - 3. Right now the flow is like this: 1 - 2 - Red box. On initial render I'm creating bunch of elements that the carousel uses as children, so the elements are in the DOM but not in the Carousel view.

Is there any way to have the tab order skip the elements that are not in the carousel view so I get the correct feeling when tab-ing from 1 - 2 - 3 ?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: If you're seriously working on improving accessibility, don't use a carousel.. they're probably the most loathed feature by visually-impaired users. If you must use it, add a 'skip to content' link that can be tabbed onto near the top of the page, and ensure ALL images have alt/title attributes, meaningfully labelled as appropriate (decorative images don't need a description but it's useful for the user to know if an image is a  'filler'.)

Comment: I really dislike carousels, It’s really not my choice I’ll just have to make the best out of it.

Comment: Fair enough.. ensure you add the skip to content link then..

Comment: w3 provides a good tutorial on accessible carousels - https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/carousels/.  they **can** be made screen reader accessible.  not everyone hates carousels.  i use a screen reader and can navigate them pretty well (when done properly, of course).  if your "off screen" objects are not properly hidden, a screen reader will be able to navigate to them.  i'm not sure if that's what you want.  if not, then when they're `display:none`, they obviously won't be tabbed to (nor available to screen readers).